# Loading 2 Singletons With Dependencies when an app is opened (appDelegate / appDidBecomeActive) iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, singleton, race-condition

I'm trying to load two standard-issue style singletons:  http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html when my iPhone app is loaded. Here's my code:

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {  
    // first, restore user prefs
    [AppState loadState];

    // then, initialize the camera
    [[CameraModule sharedCameraModule] initCamera];
}
```

My "camera module" has code that checks a property of the AppState singleton. But I think what's happening is a race condition where the camera module singleton is trying to access the AppState property while it's in the middle of being initialized (so the property is nil, and it's re-initializing AppState). I'd really like to keep these separate, instead of just throwing one (or both) into the App Delegate. Has anyone else seen something like this? What kind of workaround did you use, or what would you suggest?

Thanks in advance!

Here's the loadState method:

```
+ (void)loadState {
  @synchronized([AppState class]) {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"prefs.archive"];
    Boolean saveFileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file];

    if(saveFileExists) {
      sharedAppState = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:file] retain];
    } else {
      [AppState sharedAppState];
    }
  }
}
```

The line that calls AppState in CameraModule:

```
- (void)initCamera {
    ...

    if([AppState sharedAppState].captureSession != nil) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `loadState` code look like? Unless you're intentionally doing work on background threads, that method won't return until it's finished.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help - I just added the loadState method to the question.

Comment: What's `sharedAppState`? Can you post the code from `CameraModule` where you access the `Appstate` property?

Comment: sharedAppState is the singleton's instance... Check out the link in my post. I'm using the "SynthesizeSingleton.h" file toward the middle of the page. Sure I'll post the AppState property line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weirdest thing was happening... I was accessing a property of `AppState` in my `RootViewController`, and the order of app execution was the culprit.

`RootViewController` is loaded in my MainWindow.xib file, and apparently the XIB loading/shenanegans happens BEFORE anything inside `applicationDidFinishLaunching` so loadState was being called late in the game.

The solution was to move `[AppState loadState]` to my `RootViewController`'s init method.